# nth-child selector doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm getting dynamically results like this :

```
<div class="statusContent">
   <div class="statusBox">
     <div class="title">Title</div>
     <div class="subTitle">Subtitle</div>
   </div>

   <div class="statusBox">
     <div class="title">Title</div>
     <div class="subTitle">Subtitle</div>
   </div>

    <div class="statusBox">
     <div class="title">Title</div>
     <div class="subTitle">Subtitle</div>
   </div>

   .....
</div>
```

I do not know the numbers of div's with `statusBox` class. I'm trying to apply css for only 1, 3, 5, 7 ... div with `statusBox` class.

I try to do it with next css :

```
.statusContent div:nth-child(2n+1){
    margin-right: 2%;
  }
```

But this style is applied also for div's with `title` and `subtitle` class.

How can I apply it only for div's with `statusBox` class?

Comment: I want to select elements, but only the parent div's inside `<div class="statusContent">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.statusContent .statusBox:nth-child(odd)` This will still only work on divs that are a direct child of `.statusContent` though. You can't do `nth` based stuff on just classes

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You're right but i feel it's more verbose and people will relate to it more by having it.